# docker: how to install google chrome

Tags: docker, google-chrome

I am trying to install google chrome inside the docker container

```
FROM python:3.10.10-buster

###########################################
# Upgrade the packages
###########################################
# Download latest listing of available packages:
RUN apt-get -y update
# Upgrade already installed packages:
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

# https://nander.cc/using-selenium-within-a-docker-container
###########################################
# Install google-chrome-stable
###########################################

# Adding trusting keys to apt for repositories
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -

# Adding Google Chrome to the repositories
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'

# Updating apt to see and install Google Chrome
RUN apt-get -y update

# Magic happens
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

RUN google-chrome --product-version
```

When i try to run google-chrome inside the container i get

```
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
[31:31:0730/041954.336135:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(201)] Check failed: . : Operation not permitted (1)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```